# How to code a 5 second timer in django/Python?

Tags: python, django

Task:  (in Django - pycharm webpage)

**File/webpage-1::**

1. ~ Needs to have 1 textbox where user can  enter any number. Let's
   keep it 50 initially.
2. ~ Needs to have submit button named OK.

(Now when the user clicks OK button, it shall be redirected to file2/webpage-2)

**File2/webpage-2 ::**

1. Displays 50  After 5 seconds displays 51, again after 5 seconds
   displays 52  ... And further.
2. Its keeps on incrementing the counter after 5 second delay.

*I Presently am unfamiliar with Python and django, also applied sleep method as suggested in stack overflow but all in vain. Currently working on django installation and its tutorials.*

Comment: you will need to use javascript for this as this is something that is best done client-side.

Answer (score 5):

This is not something you can do in Django itself, since that runs only on the server. You need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Django can not handle the timer by itself. Use it to serve a web page with some javascript.

The javascript can animate and update the page on a regular timer, for example, with the [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function